# Интеграция ckeditor в Laravel 4.2

Tags: javascript, laravel, ckeditor

С помощью builder`a я собрал редактор с необходимыми модулями.

1. Как сделать загрузку картинок (Image upload)
   Я так понимаю нужно создать plugin.js, а в нем то что ?
   пример может кто-то показать
2. Ошибка Cannot read property 'icons' of null

Помогите :)

Answer (score 1):

В CKEDITOR нужно указать ссылку куда аплодить, допустим

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1',
{
    filebrowserBrowseUrl : '/browse.php',
    filebrowserUploadUrl : '/upload.php'
});
```

Ну и уже в в этих страницах написать скрипт загрухки файлов или просмотр, с Laravel будет очень просто [Команды с File](http://laravel-recipes.com/categories/20)

Можно даже зашружать в storage для закрытия доступа:
Тогда в Route  создаёшь URl для просмотра файла например:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth|hasAccess:admin'), function(){
    Route::get('/readfile', array('as' => 'readfile', 'uses' => 'Controller@readfile'));
});
example.com/readfile?filename=file.jpg
```

Создаёшь контроллер где фал будет обрабатыватся.
надеюсь поможет